# Replacing "Add To Cart" text on shop and archives pages for "specific" categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have 2 categories on my WooCommerce website. Let's say:

- "cat1"
- "cat2"

I have implemented the following code to modify the "Add To Cart" text to "View Product" for all the products.

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'replace_loop_add_to_cart_button', 10, 2 );
function replace_loop_add_to_cart_button( $button, $product  ) {
    $button_text = __( "View Product", "woocommerce" );
    return '<a class="button" href="' . $product->get_permalink() . '">' . $button_text . '</a>';
}
```

But what I don't know is how to modify the button text to "View Cat 1" for category 1 products, and "View Cat 2" for category 2 products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the solution:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'replace_loop_add_to_cart_button', 10, 2 );
function replace_loop_add_to_cart_button( $button, $product  ) {
    if( has_term( 'cat-1', 'product_cat' ) ){
    // Category 1 Button text here
    $button_text = __( "View Cat 1", "woocommerce" );
    return '<a class="button" href="' . $product->get_permalink() . '">' . $button_text . '</a>';
    } else {
    // Category 2 Button text here
    $button_text = __( "View Cat 2", "woocommerce" );
    return '<a class="button" href="' . $product->get_permalink() . '">' . $button_text . '</a>';
    }
}
```

Hope it helps those in a similar situation :)

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are doing well i add pretty simple solution for you below is your magic.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'replace_loop_add_to_cart_button', 10, 2);
function replace_loop_add_to_cart_button($button, $product)
{
    $terms = get_the_terms($product->get_id(), 'product_cat');
    $cat_list = [];
    foreach ($terms as $cat) {
         $cat_list[] = $cat->slug;
     }
     $display_cat = ['cat-1', 'cat-2'];
     if (count(array_intersect($display_cat, $cat_list)) > 0) {
          $button_text = __("View Product", "woocommerce");
          return '<a class="button" href="' . $product->get_permalink() . '">' . $button_text . '</a>';
     } else {
          return $button;
     }
}
```

your second question answer is

```
add_filter('woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'replace_loop_add_to_cart_button', 10, 2);
function replace_loop_add_to_cart_button($button, $product)
 {
     $terms = get_the_terms($product->get_id(), 'product_cat');
     $cat_list = [];
     foreach ($terms as $cat) {
          $cat_list[] = $cat->slug;
     }
     if (in_array_any('cat-1', $cat_list)) {
           $button_text = __("View Product cat-1", "woocommerce");
     } else if (in_array_any('cat-2', $cat_list)) {
           $button_text = __("View Product cat-2", "woocommerce");
     } else {
           return $button;
     }

      return '<a class="button" href="' . $product->get_permalink() . '">' . $button_text . '</a>';
}
```

Comment: Hi. I added the exact code. The following error came:

Your PHP code changes were rolled back due to an error on line 24 of file wp-content/themes/kadence-child/functions.php. Please fix and try saving again.

Comment: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function in_array_any() in wp-content/themes/kadence-child/functions.php:24
Stack trace:
#0 wp-includes/class-wp-hook

Comment: .php(305): replace_loop_add_to_cart_button()
#1 wp-includes/plugin.php(189): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#2 wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/loop/add-to-cart.php(25): apply_filters()
#3 wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-core-functions.php(345): include('/home/pujamandi...')
#4 wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php(1356): wc_get_template()
#5 wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(303): woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart()
#6 wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(327): WP_Hook->apply_filters()

Comment: #7 wp-includes/plugin.php(470): WP_Hook->